# Kubernetes Jenkins swap space issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, gcloud

Jenkins is failing to build due to "Free Swap Space" being 0. I don't know how to fix that. The build process keeps hanging. Here part of the output:

[image]

[image]

When I ssh into the instance and `docker info` I get a `WARNING: No swap limit support`.

Answer (score 5):

Your screenshot shows "waiting for next available executor" so try increasing the number of executors in jenkins ("Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "# of executors").

Also here the info how to create Swapfile (for avoiding out of memory on building large docker containers etc.). The example creates 4G swapfile at location /myswap :

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/myswap count=4096 bs=1MiB
sudo chmod 600 /myswap
sudo mkswap /myswap
sudo swapon /myswap
```

to check swap is working:

```
swapon -s
```

enable swap at boot, add line to fstab file:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add this line:

```
/myswap   swap    swap    sw  0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Lack of swap does not prevent building. If you are using kubernetes (given the tag in your question) you need to look at the Jenkins log, it will say why a container could not be created

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes [strongly recommends to disable swap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/#before-you-begin) on nodes, so it's ok that free swap space is shown as 0B.

Comment: Page is not working

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with default helm chart provided by helm hub. It turns out that `#of executors` was actually `0`.
Increasing that solved.